# Complex HTML table with rowspans and colspans is broken

Tags: html, html-table

I am struggling to display a table in HTML with a rather complicated structure and would like some help in trying to figure out what the problem might be. My goal is to print out the following table in HTML:

Desired layout

[image]

Actual layout when shown using HTML:

```css
table td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="1">
            1
        </td>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">
            2
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            3
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">
            5
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            6
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            7
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            8
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="1">
            9
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            10
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            11
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            12
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            13
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            14
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            15
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            16
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            17
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            18
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            19
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can see the result here: https://codepen.io/lexokag/pen/OJWyojq

Can you advise where do I have a mistake in my colspans/rowspans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this table, I had to leave an empty tag `<tr></tr>`, to create a row that will not allow your table to break.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

table tr {   
    height: 30px;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">test text</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">test text</td>     
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td rowspan="2">test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
            <td>test text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I believe an empty row is a key to the answer, can there be any other way as well?

Comment: @GauravGupta, Yes, maybe there is another way, but I only thought of this way.

Comment: @GauravGupta You can decrease all the rowspans by 1 and simply style the second row to be double the height: https://jsfiddle.net/g62yqorL/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Md Azad</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="black">
        <caption>Draw</caption>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  colspan="2" rowspan="3" height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"  height="60" width="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
            <td  height="30" width="100"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).